# Can I set up a template in Xamarin Forms for Xaml that's repetitive?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use the same XAML many times in my application with two minor differences which are the value of the Text and Selected that I pass in:

```
<ViewCell Tapped="selectValue" >
   <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20,0" >
      <local:StyledLabel Text="{Binding [1].Name}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
      <local:StyledLabel IsVisible="{Binding [1].IsSelected}" TextColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="End" Text="✓" />
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

Does Xamarin forms have any template feature where I could for example shorten this to something like:

```
<local:SwitchViewCell Text="{Binding [1].Name}" Selected="{Binding [1].IsSelected}" />
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          mlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese"
          x:Class="Japanese.SwitchViewCell""
          Tapped="selectValue" >
   <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20,0" >
      <local:StyledLabel Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference this}}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
      <local:StyledLabel IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible, Source={x:Reference this}}" TextColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="End" Text="✓" />
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

With this code behind right now:

```
namespace Japanese.Templates
{
    public partial class SwitchViewCell : ViewCell
    {
        public SwitchViewCell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(SwitchViewCell));
        public static readonly BindableProperty IsVisibleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsVisible), typeof(bool), typeof(SwitchViewCell));

        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(TextProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public bool IsVisible
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)GetValue(IsVisibleProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, value);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is 100% the way to go but when I try to implement this I get the message:

```
 EventHandler "selectValue" not found in type "Japanese.Templates.SwitchViewCell" (Japanese)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ListView Cell:**

For the ListView cell, you can define the ViewCell layout of ListView item.
Ex. PersonCell.xaml

```
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          x:Class="DataTemplates.PersonCell">
     <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastName}" />
        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Email}" />
    </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

Then you can use this into ListView's DataTemplate as:

```
<ListView ItemSource="{Binding PersonList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:PersonCell />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This way ListView resuses the cell design for each item.

**Reusable View:**

You can also make a reusable view which can be simply included in your page. 
Ex. MyCustomView.xaml:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Xam.Control.MyCustomView"> 
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Hello"/>
        <Label Text="How Are You?"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Page:

```
<ContentPage
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
xmlns:customView="clr-namespace:Xam.Control;assembly=Xam"
x:Class="Xam.View.HomePage">
```

Here, notice that you have to include the namespace and assembly where your custom view resides.

And then in this page, simply add it like:

```
<customView:MyCustomView />
```

Comment: Thanks Milan, but that's a bit different from my needs as I need to pass in a couple of values and also handle the tapped event. I have updated my question with what I have so far.  Maybe you can have a look at that and see if you can think of how for example to handle the tapped. Thanks

Comment: Seems like <ViewCell Tapped="selectValue"/> has not auto generated the event in its class because you might have copy pasted this line. Delete this event and name from xaml and re-write or regenerate it. If not automatically generate then you have to write this missing event method in its calss manually.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I did copy and paste into the XAML.  Can you tell me how I can make it auto generate or how i could write the missing method into the class?

Comment: I will accept your answer as I think it's the most descriptive of the two.  I have another closely related question so you will see that soon.  Thanks

Comment: Glad to know it helps. Well you can manually add the Tapped event in this class as 
void selectedValue (object sender, System.EventArgs e) { //your code goes here }

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just put it in a separate XAML file and define a the bindable properties that you need and map the values onto the controls in your custom control. In fact, the latter is not absolutely needed but is nicer to make it completely reusable.

If you just want to reuse it in your project and always data bind it to the same fields, you can leave it as-is, as the `BindingContext` will be inherited.

To get you started, you might want to have a look at a blog post of mine about this: https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/reusable-custom-usercontrols-with-bindableproperty/

Comment: Thanks Gerald,  do you know of any examples of this that I could copy as a starting point?

Comment: Updated the answer